# How to pass the value of an array as a second argument to awk's split function?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, awk

I know that in awk we pass array elements by reference but I'm wondering if there's a way to pass by value? I am trying to use the build in split function in a for loop and need the second argument (array name) to be taken from another array and reference it later. I am currently running the following command;

```
echo "test this" | awk 'BEGIN { 
  arraynametest[1] = "arrayone"; 
  for (i=1; i <= length(arraynametest); i++) { 
    split($0, arraynametest[i], /\[\[:blank:]]/); 
  }
} END { 
  print "test array with index ", i, " = ", arrayone[i] 
}'
```

with output;

```
 awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: split: second argument is not an array
```

Even if I amend to store the array value to a variable first and use the var it does not work;

```
echo "test this" | awk 'BEGIN { arraynametest[1] = "arrayone"; for (i=1; i <= length(arraynametest); i++) { arrayname = arraynametest[1]; split($0, arrayname, /\[\[:blank:]]/); }} END { print "test array with index ", i, " = ", arrayname[i] }'
```

Same output;

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: split: second argument is not an array
```

I know it will be due to the array element being passed as a reference. Is there a way around this?

My expected output would be;

```
test array with index 1 = test
```

Comment: You're really obfuscating your problem by calling split() in a loop over an array that has 1 entry instead of just calling it once, and then calling split() with a 3rd arg of `/\[\[:blank:]]/` which looks bizarre and that string doesn't exist in your input. Your example could have been as simple as asking how to do `var="arrayone"; split($0,var)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a scalar in array context or vice versa. One way to handle this is using multi-dimensional arrays, where your first index can be the array name (why not just use an index instead?)  A simplified version of your sample code...

```
$ echo "test this" | 
  awk '{arraynames[1] = "arrayone";
        data[arraynames[1]][1];  
        split($0, data[arraynames[1]]);
        print "test array with name = " (name=arraynames[1]) ", value at index 1 = " data[name][1]}'

test array with name = arrayone, value at index 1 = test
```

note also that in `BEGIN` block `$0` is not read, so even if you fix scalar/array mix you won't get any output.

Comment: thanks @karakfa ! You are of course right about the BEGIN block. I forgot about this when trying to come up with a mre, I am not using it in the BEGIN in my actual script. In terms of the index suggestion, it  makes my code way more human readable later in the script. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: You should mention that requires an awk variant that supports arrays of arrays, e.g. GNU awk.